# Visual Basic Module v Singleton

Tags: vb.net, singleton, module

So I've been programming in C# for the last 6 years or so and now I'm getting my feet wet with VB.net.

The code base I'm working with uses some modules.  To me the module looks a lot like a singleton.  Only one exists; it can be called anywhere inside the namespace.

Is there something I'm missing here? Does VB not support the normal way a singleton is structured (private constructor/public instance field)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Modules are not a singleton.  It is much more akin to a static class in C#.  If you decompile the code you will see they have a very similar structure (modules have an extra attribute).

The major differences between a C# static class and a VB.Net module are ...

- Don't have to add Static / Shared qualifiers to methods in a module.  They are Shared by default and you cannot change this
- If a Module is in an Imported namespace, all of its methods are available without qualification.
- Static classes in C# can be generic, modules cannot (although they can have generic members)

Comment: So basically with a module it's like going through and declaring everyting inside static (which would be required in C#). 

Then the difference between that and a singleton is that a singleton supports inheritance (as a derived class, or from a interface) and polymorphism, where the module just is what it is? I'm just tring to sort it all out.

Comment: @Joel, kind of. The important thing to remember about module is there is no instance ever.  Under the hood it compiles down to a set of static methods (just like C# static classes).  The biggest difference is they get added to the global name scope if the containing module is available.

Answer (score 3):

If I'm not mistaken, a VB module is the same thing as a static class.

Comment: There are subtle differences between the 2 but yes at a high level they are the same.